# How to change the duration of a movement with count- Swift SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

In my game, there's a class for a "wall" that's moving to the left. I want to change the speed of it based on count `i` that I added to `touchesBegan` method:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent {
    count++
}

func startMoving() {

    let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-kDefaultXToMovePerSecond, y: 0, duration: 1 )

    let move = SKAction.moveByX(-kDefaultXToMovePerSecond, y: 0, duration: 0.5)

    if(count <= 10)
    {
        runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveLeft))
    }
    else
    {
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(move))
    }
}
```

but it's not working. Can you help?

Comment: It looks like you are running an action on the scene. Try running an action on wall node.

Comment: I'm running this on the wall class

Comment: It doesn't looks like that from the code you've posted. Is startMoving() method a member of Wall class or GameScene class? If it's member of GameScene class, then you should do something like this: wallNode.runAction(...) instead of runAction(...)

Comment: All of this code is in the Wall class, I juat added the touchesBegun: http://tinypic.com/r/1058576/8

Comment: So you are calling the startMoving() method inside node's init method, right ? In that case counter is always equal to 0 thus, else block from startMoving() method is never executed. And actually, I am not sure what is the main problem here ? Does wall node move at all ? Is there a problem with receiving touches on wall node ?

Comment: Also, I am not sure what are you trying to accomplish with implementing touchesBegan on wall node. I see how Nimble Ninja works, but those walls are just obstacles which are moving pretty fast. I am not sure if you can make 10 touches ever because of a wall's speed. Keep in mind that count variable you've added is local to that particular wall node... And it will be incremented when user touch that certain wall node.

Comment: The walls are generated per 1 second, and I want that when the user taps 10 times for example on the screen to switch side, the speed of the walls generation will increase.

Comment: If you counting taps on screen and not on particular nodes then you don't need to implement touches began on walls. Probably you could go with changing the MLWall's init method to init(duration:NSTimeInterval) and use that duration inside startMoving() method. And in your scene's touchesBegan you have to track number of touches and to create (initialize with appropriate duration) wall nodes... Let me try that by myself and if I came up with something useful, I will post an answer...

Comment: Okay, I have managed to change the speed, but be aware that there are a lot of things you should change in order to work. There is WallGenerator class etc which has to be changed and a few methods also needed duration parameter. So, that's a lot of changes :) I will post some answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

As I said there are a lot of changes which have to be done:

First let's change MLWall class and add a duration property which will be used in startMoving method:

```
var duration:NSTimeInterval = 0.5
```

Then still inside MLWall class change the init method:

```
 init(duration: NSTimeInterval) {

        self.duration = duration

       //...
    }
```

And change startMoving method to use this passed parameter:

```
func startMoving() {

        let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-kDefaultXToMovePerSecond, y: 0, duration: self.duration)
        runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveLeft))
    }
```

Those are changes inside Wall class. Now let's make some changes in WallGenerator class:

First WallGenerator class should be aware of how fast walls should go. So we are adding property to store that info:

```
var currentDuration: NSTimeInterval = 1 // I named it duration, because SKAction takes duration as a parameter, but this actually affects on speed of a wall.
```

After that the first method which has to be changed is startGeneratingWallsEvery(second:) into startGeneratingWallsEvery(second: duration:

```
//duration parameter added
    func startGeneratingWallsEvery(seconds: NSTimeInterval, duration : NSTimeInterval) {

       self.currentDuration = duration

        generationTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(seconds, target: self, selector: "generateWall", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }
```

Here, we are making a WallGenerator aware of desired wall's speed. 
And the next method which has to be changed in order to use that speed is:

```
//duration parameter added
    func generateWall() {
        //...
        //Duration parameter added

        let wall = MLWall(duration: self.currentDuration)
       //...
    }
```

And there is a GameScene left. There, I've added a tapCounter property:

```
let debugLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Arial") //I've also added a debug label to track taps count visually
var tapCounter = 0
```

Here is  how you can initialize label if you want to see number of tap counts:

```
 //Setup debug label

        debugLabel.text = "Tap counter : \(tapCounter)"
        debugLabel.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(frame), y: CGRectGetMaxY(frame)-50.0)
        debugLabel.fontColor = SKColor.purpleColor()
        self.addChild(debugLabel)
```

First I've changed the start method:

```
func start() {
       //...

        // adding duration parameter in method call
        wallGenerator.startGeneratingWallsEvery(1,duration: 1)
    }
```

The important part is :  `wallGenerator.startGeneratingWallsEvery(1,duration: 1)` which says start generating walls every second with one second duration(which affects on node's speed).

Next, I've modified touchesBegan of the scene into this:

```
if isGameOver {
            restart()
        } else if !isStarted {
            start()
        } else {



            tapCounter++
            debugLabel.text = "Tap counter : \(tapCounter)"

            if(tapCounter > 10){
                wallGenerator.stopGenerating()
                wallGenerator.startGeneratingWallsEvery(0.5, duration:0.5)
            }

            hero.flip()
        }
```

Then, changed restart() method in order to restart the counter when game ends:

```
func restart() {
        tapCounter = 0
       //...
 }
```

And that's pretty much it. I guess I haven't forgot something, but at my side it works as it should. Also, note that using NSTimer like from this [GitHub project](https://github.com/prometheon/MLNimbleNinja) is not what you want in SpriteKit. That is because NSTimer don't respect scene's , view's or node's paused state. That means it will continue with spawning walls even if you think that game is paused. SKAction would be a preferred replacement for this situation.

Hope this helps, and if you have further questions, feel free to ask, but I guess that you can understand what's happening from the code above. Basically what is done is that WallGenerator has become aware of how fast their wall nodes should go, and Wall node has become aware of how fast it should go...

**EDIT:**

There is another way of changing walls speed by running an  moving action with key. Then, at the moment of spawning, based on tapCounter value, you can access an moving action by the key, and directly change actions's speed property...This is probably a shorter way, but still requires some changes (passing a duration parameter inside Wall class and implementing tapCounter inside scene).

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try doing it like so :</strike>

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent {
    count++
    startMoving()

}

func startMoving() {
    removeAllActions()
    let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-kDefaultXToMovePerSecond, y: 0, duration: count <= 10 ? 1.0 : 0.5)
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveLeft))

}
```

As of I read comments below your question, you made a really unclear question, but nevertheless you have idealogical problems in your code.

Your `touchesBegan` method is implemented in the wall if I understood everything right, so it has no effect on newly generated walls. You have to move that logic to the scene and then spawn new walls with speed as a parameter, or at least make `count` a class var, so every wall can access that, but you still has to handle your touches in the scene, because now touch is handled when user taps directly in the wall.

Comment: This isn't working... boath of the actions are working together. I need it to go first per 1 second and then per 0.5 a second

Comment: The code I've provided allows your instance to move per `kDefaultXToMovePerSecond` every second until count is equal or more than 10, then It will move by `kDefaultXToMovePerSecond` every half second. Is this a desired behavior?

Comment: @s1ddok She is trying to change the speed of moving walls , but there is a WallGenerator class which spawn Walls with predetermined size. And because of Wall node is not aware of number of touches on the screen, it should be initialized with desired speed. There is a GitHub project called Nimble Ninja...You can download it and see by yourself what I am talking about...

Comment: I meant to say : "WallGenerator class which spawn Walls with predetermined speed" (not size :)

Comment: Well I'm not into researching someone else's project, I just tried to help OP to understand, that he is wrong with a design.